# php multi exec is slow (19 minutes?)

Tags: php, c++, curl, exec

I have a curl_multi_exec call to about 500 sites which it calls via an array loop:

I am using the simplified code:

http://github.com/kminkler/php-curl-multi/wiki

but it gets VERRRY slow (19 minutes) towards the end...

do I need to remove the handle every time is this a memory issue;

Would you rec. writing a C++ curl routine

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [MultiRequest](http://code.google.com/p/multirequest/) library.